# Is it possible to lower the range of BLE devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have two devices I want to communicate over BLE, but I want the signal range to be limited to a few meters. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you can set the TX power, you can set a very low power, such as -20 dBm. Then the range will only be a few meters. Depending on your platform, this may or may not be possible to configure.

Comment: Thanks, everything i've read thus far has indicated this but I had some confusion about whether that would work.

Comment: You should of course also do your own measurements, to verify that the signal becomes too weak to be detected further away than acceptable.